# Using Task.Factory.StartNew() Then Return Value

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a class that has a few tasks that are created and occur.  When I run my test app an example of the threads created/used are as follows...

- Thread9 (Main Thread)
- Thread9
- Thread9
- Thread10 (Worker StartNew Thread)
- Thread11 (Worker ContinueWith Thread)
- Thread11

I'm able to pass an object from my main thread(9) into a worker thread(10) and from the worker thread into the worker ContinueWith thread(11) [AKA the completion of the worker thread(10)].  Everything I do works great with one exception...  I can't seem to get that object back to the main thread using something like an event.  Whenever I try to delegate or Invoke back to the main thread it will not work.  It always fires on Thread11 instead of Thread9!

My goal is to get the object (being used in Thread11) back to the main Thread9.

Notes:

- I can not use .Wait() or pause the MainUI in any way.
- I can not use Task.WaitAll() or Task.WaitAny() as it will freeze the UI too.
- Invoke will not work because this is a custom class and not a form.

---

UPDATED - Example:

```
private SQLConnectionProperties sql = new SQLConnectionProperties();

private void SQLTest()
{
    //Being called from main UI thread 9
    sql.SQLErrorMessage = "FIRST CHANGE";
    Task<SQLConnectionProperties> taskConnect = Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => threadConnect(sql), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default)
        .ContinueWith((task) => threadConnect(task.Result, true));
    //Continue back to main UI (still in main UI thread 9)
}

private SQLConnectionProperties threadConnect(SQLConnectionProperties sql, bool bContinuation = false)
{
    if (!bContinuation)
    {
        //In new thread 10
        sql.SQLErrorMessage = "SECOND CHANGE";
    }
    else
    {
        //In new thread 11
        sql.SQLErrorMessage = "THIRD CHANGE";
    }
    return sql;
}
```

Using the above code I would have everything I want up until the `In new thread 11` line.  After SQLErrorMessage is changed to "THIRD CHANGE" and it gets returned I need some type of event to be raised or something to get the results back to the main UI thread 9.

Comment: Have you tried using async/await along with these tasks?

Comment: Added a small rough example.  Does that better explain it?  @Ron, await would need to be called right after the task is created/started and would stop the main UI thread wouldn't it?

Comment: Found this nice article about async/await.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx  but still can't see how using them would be helpful for my situation.  Maybe add an answer to show me what you're talking about?  Also, how is this question off-topic?  It has to do with programming and fits in perfectly for SO...

Comment: This is a clear example of [an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You are talking about tasks and threads, where it really sounds like you want to know how to connect to SQL asynchronously without blocking the UI.   Also - tasks are not threads, you are using the terms interchangeably.  And - Async/Await is indeed the key to the solution - but you're not going to get a whole example written for you in a single post.  Search the web for more articles.  [Start with this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: @MattJohnson I don't claim to be all knowing about what I'm talking about but I respectfully disagree.  I don't think this is an XY problem at all.  I'm not trying to learn how to connect to SQL or how to connect asynchronously.  I already do that.  My question is really clear.  I just want to know how to get an object from a worker THREAD to the main THREAD.  Also I disagree with your statement about the tasks and threads.  A task indeed DOES create a new thread if created correctly.  I'm not using the terms incorrectly.

Comment: @ArvoBowen "A task indeed DOES create a new thread if created correctly."  That is strictly false, and demonstrates a severe lack of understanding about what a `Task` is, and how its supposed to be used.  It also sounds like you don't really understand the basic idea of asynchronous, and how it's different from multithreading.  While you haven't actually explained what your actual work is, there's a strong chance it can be done without the use of any non-UI threads at all, as Matt has said.  Rather than assuming you're well versed in these topics, assume you aren't and read those tutorials.

Comment: @Servy , in my mind it's simple...  Not every task needs or creates a new thread.  As I said and you quoted, "a new thread IF created correctly" I meant that a task COULD BE a new thread.  I'm not saying that they are one in the same but they yield similar results.  For my situation and everything this question was based on the task created IS (creates) a new thread!  To test this its very simple, put the following line in before the "task" is created and then again WITHIN the task created... `Debug.WriteLine("ThreadID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);`

Comment: @Servy , the ONLY person that provided an answer was r00tdev.  He answered my question perfectly.  As my question title states I just want to use Task.Factory.StartNew() then return a value (to the UI's thread).  Also, you're kind of just going off on a tangent.  Where did I ever "claim the UI is blocked"?  Where did I ever mention the word "Timer".  I don't deny you or others might have some type of working solution, but instead of telling someone that what they are doing is not working (which mine clearly is) how about helping and provide an answer with code to actually contribute.  Thanks.

Comment: My apologies about my previous (now deleted) comment, I mixed up your question with another similar question.  That said, Matt's original points are correct in that *you're trying to solve the wrong problem*.  Yes, someone answered the question that you actually asked, but going down this path is only going to cause you more problems, as it's not addressing core problems with what you're trying to do.  The fact that you don't care about that, and are only interested in a short term fix at the expense of long term sustainability is on you.

Comment: @Servy, agreed :)  I'm just trying to learn.  I'm more then likely approaching this from the wrong angle but this is my first time working with Tasks and I'm having fun with it.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @r00tdev explained, using the SynchronizationContext() class is the solution to what I was trying to do.  Below you will see an example of how I used it to get the results of the worker thread back to the main UI thread.  Thanks for the answer @r00tdev!

---

Example:

```
private void SQLTest()
{
    //Set up a sync context back to this main UI thread
    m_sql.SyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    //Being called from main UI thread 9
    m_sql.SQLErrorMessage = "FIRST CHANGE";
    Task<SQLConnectionProperties> taskConnect = Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => threadConnect(m_sql), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default)
        .ContinueWith((task) => threadConnect(task.Result, true));
    //Continue back to main UI (still in main UI thread 9)
}

private SQLConnectionProperties threadConnect(SQLConnectionProperties sql, bool bContinuation = false)
{
    if (!bContinuation)
    {
        //In new thread 10
        sql.SQLErrorMessage = "SECOND CHANGE";
    }
    else
    {
        //In new thread 11
        sql.SQLErrorMessage = "THIRD CHANGE";

        sql.SyncContext.Post(threadConnectComplete, sql);
    }
    return sql;
}

private void threadConnectComplete(object state)
{
    //Back in the main UI thread!  Save the changes to the sql object
    SQLConnectionProperties sql = state as SQLConnectionProperties;
    m_sql = sql;

    //See the results and use this area to update the main UI
    Debug.WriteLine("SQLErrorMessage:" + sql.SQLErrorMessage);

    //TESTING NON THREAD SAFE just to show you no runtime errors happen
    form_MainUI.textbox1.Text = sql.SQLErrorMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `_synchronizationContext.Send` or `_synchronizationContext.Post` to communicate with UI thread.

Also, from what you have mentioned, I think you also need to pass "false" when calling either of above functions so that it knows that the function is not invoked from UI thread.

```
_synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
```

Comment: Thanks @r00tdev I'll give it a shot.  Think you might be able to give an example by chance?

Comment: Do to limited MSDN resources about this subject I had to turn to this page for a great artical on SynchronizationContext.  This sounds like EXACTLY what I needed!  I'm giving it a try now and if it works I will give the answer to you.  I might update the answer with an example if you don't get to it first.  ;)  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I

Comment: Well @r00tdev sorry, I tried to give the answer to you but it seems the votes came in 3 to 2 (not in favor of my edit adding an example).  So it forced me to add an answer of my own.  Answers are much more helpful with an example and I can't imagine why in the world my edit would have been rejected, it was clearly to IMPROVE the answer for the community...